# comparison of proportion to a population CI

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, point-estimation

I am comparing the % of minorities from my organization to a population % of minorities, to see if it is high or low. I have data for my whole organization (not a sample) so I do not show CIs. The “population” data is a sample and thus has CIs. For example, see the below (hypothetical) data.

[image]

Question #1: if my organization value is within the CI population range, can say it is “consistent” with the population data?

Question #2: If my organization value is outside the CI population range interval, is it correct to stay there is a statistically significant difference, or should I just say it is “higher” or “lower” compared to the population?

Comment: At the outset, by insisting you will view your data as a population, you essentially deny there is any meaning for you in statistical "significance:" either the proportions are equal or they are not.  In many cases, regardless of how the data are obtained, it can be useful to analyze them *as if* they were a random sample from a reference population.  That's one way to give your question some meaning and utility.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways to illustrate that confidence intervals
for the population and company employees can be
considered as arising from random samples from the
population or the employees. Such speculation
requires a careful statement of the assumptions.

It seems that the 'population' confidence intervals must
have been based on samples of size something like
100 or 150 randomly chosen members of the population.

For example, if there were 50 'minority' people in a sample
of 100, then the `prop.test` procedure in R would give
a 95% CI of about $(.40, .60)$ as in your table.

```
prop.test(50, 100)$conf.int
[1] 0.4038315 0.5961685
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

Similarly, if there were 30 minority people
in a sample of 150, then we would get a 95% CI about $(15\%, 25\%).$

```
prop.test(round(.2*150), 150)$conf.int
[1] 0.1409765 0.2747707
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

Conversely, suppose you believe the population from which your
company hires is about 50% minority. Also, suppose your
company has $n=1000$ employees of whom $X$ are minority. It seems reasonable to model
the number of minority employees
as $X \sim \mathsf{Biom}(1000, 0.5).$

Then, assuming no bias in the hiring from that population pool, you would be about 95% sure to have between 470 and 531
minority employees, inclusive. Instead, it seems you have 700. [In R, `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, and `qbinom` is a binomial quantile function (inverse CDF).]

```
qbinom(c(.025,.975), 1000, .5)
[1] 469 531

diff( pbinom(c(469,531), 1000, .5) )
[1] 0.9500155
```

Put another way, testing $H_0: p = .5$ against
$H_a: p \ne .5$ with data $X = 700$ in $n = 100$
leads to a P-value very near $0,$ and strong rejection of $H_0.$

```
prop.test(700, 1000, .5)

        1-sample proportions test 
        with continuity correction

data:  700 out of 1000, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 159.2, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
 true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.6703646 0.7280778
sample estimates:
   p 
 0.7
```

Notice that it is important to consider whether
the "population" matches the pool of realistic
candidates for jobs at the company. For example,
if very many of the minority members of the population are under 18 years of age, and thus
not eligible for employment, it is not appropriate
to use overall population information to model
how the company hires employees.

Comment: Thank you! For the "population" confidence intervals, they were based on a stratified sampling design, involving probability proportional to size or systematic random sampling. Does this meet the assumptions of a "random sample?" Note - the data is hypothetical.

Comment: Stratified sample is not totally random, but for some purposes may be better. Width of a CI based on stratified sample may be different than with of CI based on random sample of same size. Computations based on fictitious data should look like those based on actual data, but it would have been nice to know they're fictitious for purposes of giving a useful answer.